# Deserialize a JSON array as Dictionary with JSON.Net

Tags: json, json.net

I've one part of my JSON that looks like this:

[image]

Like you can see, in the JSON, the temperature "dictionary", is in fact a list of list of 2 element.

The first element is a timestamp, the second the temperature. Not sure why the provider of the service did it like this, but I don't really have the choice, I must do with it.

But in my C# object, I would like to have this as a dictionary, with timestamp as the key, and temperature as the value.

Is this possible?

```
//note, I've a custom converter that converts from long to DateTime     
public Dictionary<DateTime, double> Temperature { get; set; }
```

and deserializing like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherPredictionDay>>(content, new EpochConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with a custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
class TemperatureArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Dictionary<DateTime, double>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray ja = JArray.Load(reader);
        var dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        foreach (JArray item in ja)
        {
            var key = item[0].ToObject<DateTime>(serializer);
            var val = item[1].ToObject<double>(serializer);
            dict.Add(key, val);
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, just mark your `Temperature` property with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TemperatureArrayConverter))]
public Dictionary<DateTime, double> Temperature { get; set; }
```

Note: the above converter as written is intended to work with your existing `EpochConverter` to convert the timestamp values into `DateTimes` for the dictionary keys.

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TdxYjj